# Why are there 7 total horcruxes when Voldemort intended for 7 original horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

All the horcruxes are as follows:

1. Tom Riddle's Diary
2. Marvolo Gaunt's Ring
3. Salazar Slytherin's Locket
4. Helga Hufflepuff's Cup
5. Rowena Ravenclaw's Diadem
6. Nagini
7. Harry Potter

My question is though why there aren't more horcruxes? 8 to be exact. When we see Slughorn's memory, we see that Voldemort was planning on not making 1, but 7 horcruxes. However, he only made 6, and Harry was an unintended horcrux making 7.

What happened here? We even know that Voldemort wanted 7 because it was the most magically powerful number, so it would stand to reason he makes 7 horcruxes, then Harry is an unintended 8th.